# How can I keep a live copy of a sql server 2000 table when the copied table might have a different schema? Using triggers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables in two different databases (on the same server) with possibly different schemas. `Table 1` is the `master table`, all updates will go directly there. `Table 2` is going to be `mirrored`: I need to keep table 2 the same as table 1 somehow in real time.

The catch is that table 2 might have extra columns, different column data types, primary keys added, foreign keys added etc. In spite of all this though, table 2 needs to support all queries certain legacy front ends are generating.

I was scheming today that I could mirror these possibly 'different' by attempting to re-execute the update, insert, and delete statements against table two in the second database inside of a trigger. If the trigger fails, the whole operation fails, so theoretically this should keep the tables the same.

I'm stuck on getting the actual sql statement that triggered the trigger, though.

```
fn_get_sql


DECLARE @Handle varbinary(64)
select @Handle = sql_handle FROM master..sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID
select text FROM ::fn_get_sql(@Handle)
```

This returns the sql of the trigger, not the statement though.

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)
```

This returns the first 256 characters of the sql statement.. not good enough.

My first question is: How can I get the sql statement that's triggering the trigger in sql 2000?

My second question is: Is there a better way to do this? Can I use replication to replicate tables where one table has a different schema than another (extra columns, different data types for the columns etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood how triggers work; there is no need to find the text of the query which causes the trigger to fire.

SQL Server triggers operate on temporary tables called `inserted` and `deleted`, which contain the new and old versions of the rows affected by an `UPDATE` statement. For `INSERT` and `DELETE` operations, only the `inserted` or `deleted` tables are populated respectively.
See the [SQL 2000 trigger documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more details.

It should be possible to use triggers to maintain `table 2`, assuming that there is a one-to-one relationship between the rows in it and `table 1`.

Another alternative which you might consider is to replace `table 2` with a view built on `table 1`, as long as the transformations are simple. As long as the view has the same a the original object and the necessary permissions are granted, the change should be transparent to client applications.
This would need to be tested, since it may have negative performance implications if you need to join other tables to `table 2` on columns where the datatypes have changed.

Replication is not really suitable for this task and would not work at all if `table 1` and `table 2` are in the same database; replication publishers and subscribers must be in different databases.

Comment: you're right, i found out about the inserted and deleted tables in the triggers just about an hour ago. What I need to know now is given the content of these tables, and the name of a table, how would I automatically generate the insert update or delete statements i need?

Comment: I think I would post these statements to a queue to be executed by something else. You mentioned the one to one requirement for the rows: Unfortunately I can't guarantee this: I had to remove some orphaned rows so the new application would function in the second database

Comment: @IBC - do both tables share a common key which can be used to link a row in one table to a row in the other?

Comment: the vast majority of the time, yes. If they don't, I could press for changes to the table 1 schema to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach to answer both the questions. I generally avoid using triggers until it is the last choice as it adds un-necessary overhead on the database.

Comparision between triggers and stored procedure

- It is easy to view table relationships , constraints, indexes, stored
  procedure in database but triggers are difficult to view.
- Triggers execute invisible to client-application application. They
  are not visible or can be traced in debugging code.
- It is easy to forget about triggers and if there is no documentation
  it will be difficult to figure out for new developers for their
  existence.
- Triggers run every time when the database fields are updated and it
  is overhead on system. It makes system run slower.

Enough said, this is why I prefer stored procs. You can create a job file (say for ex : it executes after every 30 min, or any other time) via agent. You can use the logic for insertion in that job file.
In this way your data in `table2` would be near to real time.

now reference to create an agent :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191128(v=sql.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a view that returns the data from your master table formatted into the structure your legacy application expects. No latency issues, no duplication of data storage.

Comment: I always thought views were just for looking at things, but it seems you can update them too... I may be able to use them. Thanks.

Comment: Some can be updated, some can't. It depends on the makeup of the view.